# If $\cos x + \cos y - \cos(x+y) = \frac{3}{2}$, then how are $x$ and $y$ related?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$\cos x + \cos y - \cos(x+y) = \frac{3}{2}$$ then
>
> - (a) $x + y = 0$
> - (b) $x = 2 y$
> - (c) $x = y$
> - (d) $2 x = y$

It is problem of trigonometry, and I have the solution of the problem. However, after seeing the solution, I don't quite understand how is one supposed to know how to approach this problem. My request is:

> Don't just solve the problem, but also tell me from where do you come to know which approach would work. (Tell me from where do you come to know which trick or approach to be used to solution this problem.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is only one answer supposed to be correct?

Comment: Yes only one answer is correct

Comment: are you sure that the problem is correct?

Comment: Yes the question is correct and the answer Is C

Comment: If $(x,y)$ satisfies the equation $\cos x+\cos y +\cos(x+y)={3\over2}$, then so does $(x+2\pi,y)$, so actually *none* of the proffered answers is correct as a logical necessity.

Comment: You are not meant to actually try and *solve* each equation, as this is a multiple choice question and you could waste a lot of time. A) obviously has no solution, and B) and D) have no real solution, as it turns out! Elimination is the name of the game.

Answer (score 6):

For a fixed value of $y\in[-\pi,\pi]$, let we consider the stationary points of the function
$$ f(x)=\cos(x)+\cos(y)-\cos(x+y)-\frac{3}{2}.$$
Since $f'(x) = -\sin(x)+\sin(x+y)$, $\,f(x)$ attains its maximum and minumum value over $[-\pi,\pi]$ at $x=\frac{\pi-y}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{\pi+y}{2}$. In particular
$$ f\left(-\frac{\pi+y}{2}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}+\cos(y)-2\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) $$
$$ f\left(\frac{\pi-y}{2}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}+\cos(y)+2\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) $$
and $f$ is bounded between these values. In order that $f(x)=0$ has some solution, the product of such values has to be $\leq 0$, that is equivalent to:
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left(1-2\cos y\right)^2 \color{red}{\leq} 0 $$
so, in order that $f(x)=0$ has some solution, $y$ has to be $\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$, and the associated solution is a stationary point. Now it is straightforward to check that $\color{red}{(c)}$ is the correct answer.

---

Obviously this solution requires time. In a test, assuming that there actually is a correct answer, it is way faster to notice that $(b)$ and $(d)$ are equivalent and $(a)$ is absurd, hence $(c)$ is the only plausible option. Nitpickers may be happy to notice that $x=\frac{7\pi}{3},y=\frac{\pi}{3}$ is a solution that violates all the given options!

Answer (score 6):

Let $z_1 = -\cos x + i\sin x$, $z_2 = -\cos y + i\sin y$. Then,
\begin{align*}
|1+z_1+z_2|^2 \geq 0 &\Rightarrow 3 -2\cos x - 2\cos y + 2\cos(x+y) \geq 0\\
&\Rightarrow \cos x + \cos y - \cos(x+y) \leq \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
Equality holds if and only if $1 + z_1 + z_2 = 0$ and hence $1+\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2} =0$. Adding, we obtain, $\cos x + \cos y = 1$ and consequently $\cos(x+y) = -\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $x+y = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and from $\cos x + \cos y = 1 $, we get $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $y = \frac{\pi}{3}$. Thus $x=y$

This can also be solved without using complex numbers:
\begin{align*}
&\qquad \cos x + \cos y - \cos(x+y) = \frac{3}{2} \\
&\Rightarrow 2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) - 2\cos^2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) + 1 = \frac{3}{2} \\
&\Rightarrow 4\cos^2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)  - 4\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) +1 = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \left(2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right)^2 + 1 - \cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) = 0\\
&\Rightarrow \left(2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right)^2  + \sin^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)  = 0
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) &= 0\\
2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) &= 0
\end{align*}
Thus $x=y = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Very nice. Do you think there is a way to do it without involving complex numbers?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a method not using complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Answer B) and D) are essentially the same due to symmetry.
For answer A) if we plug in $x+y=0$ in $cos(x+y)$ we get $cosx+cosy=5/2$ which cannot have a real solution since the sum of these cosines cannot exceed $2$. That leaves us with option C)

Comment: Yes the correct answer is C

Comment: this question is quite tricky

Comment: But I want full (subjective) solution

Comment: It's a multiple choice question. The way how I look it at is that this is not a question specifically designed to solve in order to reach the correct answer. (I wouldn't know if that even can be done after reading Barry's comment above). It is a principle of elimination. Since there can only be one answer in multiple choice, "symmetric" answers are always automatically out. For A the only thing you need is essentially amplitudes...

Comment: Hey imranfat, can you explain me how "symmetric" answers are always automatically out?

Comment: Hey imranfat, can you please explain me how "symmetric" answers are always automatically out? And why for A there is no real solution?

Comment: In a multiple choice question, there is only ONE correct answer, or ALL of them are correct (In this case there should be an option E) stating All of the above). So in your question, there is no option "All of the above". Therefore only one answer can be right. Now in case of B) and D) there are really the same. If you replace $x$ by $2y$ you get exactly the same equation as when you replace $y$ by $2x$, it doesn't make a difference if the equation is expressed in $x$ or $y$. That's why these answers are out. A) is out because the masimum of sin and cos is $1$ and 1+1$ is less than $5/2$

Answer (score 1):

HINT...If only one answer can be true you can eliminate b and d since they are both the same.
You can eliminate a automatically...

Comment: Yes, thought so too

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\cos x+\cos y=2\cos\dfrac{x+y}2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2$$

Double angle formula says:

$$\cos(x+y)=2\cos^2\dfrac{x+y}2-1$$

So we have $$2\cos^2\dfrac{x+y}2-2\cos\dfrac{x+y}2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2+\dfrac12=0\ \ \ \  (1)$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\cos\dfrac{x+y}2$ which is real,

so the discriminant $\left(2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2\right)^2-4=-4\sin^2\dfrac{x-y}2$  must be $\ge0$

So we must have $\sin^2\dfrac{x-y}2=0\implies\dfrac{x-y}2\equiv0\pmod\pi\implies x\equiv y\pmod{2\pi}$

Consequently, $(1)$ becomes,  $$2\cos^2\dfrac{x+y}2-2\cos\dfrac{x+y}2+\dfrac12=0\ \ \ \  (2)\implies\cos\dfrac{x+y}2=\dfrac12$$

$$\implies\dfrac{x+y}2=2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3\iff\cdots$$
 where $m$ is any integer

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you come to know that you have to use discriminant I order to solve this problem and how did you know that the equation is real . See the problem is I don't have good maths coaching where i live , so could you please help me with this.